# Cannot Open Raster Dataset

Tags: c++, raster, gdal

Making my way from Python to C++ (I've been programming in Python 2 years now), I stumbled in the examples of the GDAL API for raster processing. The very first example gave me some problems.
I wrote this code to open a raster on my computer, and write a message if there is any problem by opening the raster.

Here my code:

```
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h" /* for CPLMalloc() */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    GDALDatasetH hDataset;

    GDALAllRegister();

    hDataset = GDALOpen("Isle_wight.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    if ( hDataset == NULL)
    {cout << "Invalid Raster Dataset"<< endl;}
    else { cout << "Dataset open correctly!" << endl;}

    return 0;
}
```

I know that can be very trivial, but I can't understand this error message at compiling time:

```
g++ -o gdal_open_dataset gdal_open_dataset.cpp

/tmp/cc2ehnnc.o: In function `main':
gdal_open_dataset.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to                          'GDALAllRegister'
gdal_open_dataset.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `gdalOpen'     collect2:error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Your code is correct, but when you compile it fails to **link** correctly with the GDAL library. You can tell that because the error message is from `ld` the *"link loader"*. You need to add something like `-l gdal` to your `g++` command.

Comment: You need to tell your linker to add the GDAL library symbols to your executable. You should be passing the `-lgdal` flag to your compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this out. I'll let you know if it works.